# Does RegisterNatives require a function declared with JNIEXPORT or JNICALL in JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Does `JNIEXPORT` or `JNICALL` have to be used in a declaration of a function that implements a JNI native method that is not loaded from a dynamic library, but registered with a JNI function [`RegisterNatives`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734)?

For example:

```
/* Is JNIEXPORT or JNICALL required here? */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
  /* ... */
}

JNINativeMethod method = {"test", "()V", (void*)test};
env->RegisterNatives(cls, &method, 1);
```

My understanding is that `JNICALL` is required because it specifies the correct calling convention, but `JNIEXPORT` is not necessary because it is for exporting the function from a dynamic library. However, I haven't found a confirmation in the JNI documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JNIEXPORT` simply makes sure that functions marked with it are added to the library's export table. This is necessary for JNI's auto-linking of native methods because otherwise those entry points (and their names) would be lost at link-time or might even be optimized out if they are never used elsewhere in the code. `JNICALL` is not explicitly required, it is simply required that the function has the correct calling convention. But if the calling convention is correct, if the method pointer points to executable memory and if the code at that address doesn't fuck it up (exception, wrong calling convention, wrong arguments if the calling convention includes callee cleanup, ...), then you can use any method pointer and you are not restricted to methods marked with `JNIEXPORT`.

Source: Personal experience. I once wrote a library that could completely dynamically create and register native JNI method stubs that would collect their parameters into and array and then call a generic handler function.